# How to make both window active / visible in visionOS?

Tags: swift, swiftui, visionos

Two Windows are opened liken this:

```swift
@main
struct DragAndDropApp: App {
    var sharedState = SharedState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        WindowGroup (id: "SecondWindow"){
            ContentView2()
                .environmentObject(sharedState).colorScheme(.dark)
        }

        ImmersiveSpace(id: "ImmersiveSpace") {
            ImmersiveView()
        }.immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.full), in: .full)
    }
}
```

But only the selected one is visible with full intensity. Why, how can I make both active?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because the two windows are overlapping. I explained that already in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77174941/9090880). Hope it helps!