# Multiple Windows Vision OS

Tags: ios, swiftui, visionos, vision-pro

I'm currently working on a full space/immersive view. In other AR/VR development kits, it is possible to set a default position when windows open, and they can all be viewed at the same time. On VisionOS, so far I have only seen windows pop up directly in front of the user, though they can be moved. However, only one window is in focus at a time.

I have seen no examples of multiple windows in a full space, and when i added it in, it worked the same as a shared space, where you had to move the windows yourself and they would blur if there are multiple windows. The default position modifiers do not work in VisionOs.. I am unable to add any images to this post unfortunately, but im looking for something like this (The image is listed under multi window support) https://9to5mac.com/2023/06/21/visionos-gives-us-a-closer-look-at-what-well-see-with-apple-vision-pro-gallery/ on this example, the other windows are a normal size and not blurred out in Vision OS, so theoretically this is possible but i have thus far not found any example or answer on it.

need multiple windows
need them all the same size and next to each other
need default position when they are opened
need all windows in focus
windows should not be overlapping

edit: the visionos safari app does exactly what i want with multiple windows on one tab. is there a way to see how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

For general reference there is a good article about how to show multiple windows on visionOS by [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/presenting-windows-and-spaces).

As far as I understand your question, you don't want the blurring of not active windows (correct me if I'm wrong). The blur effect only happens if the two or more windows overlap. You can try that yourself in the simulator. See my attached screenshots.

##### No blurring:

[image: No blurring]

##### Blurring:

[image: Blurring]